# What are all the elements of the expression returned by KalmanEstimator used for?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

The first  "Application" in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KalmanEstimator.html) for `KalmanEstimator` is copied below with additional variables for clarity.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a={{0.5,0.07869},{0,-0.60653}};
b={{0.0042,0.0104},{0.0786,0.00786}};
c={{1,0}};
d={{0,0}};
antenna=StateSpaceModel[{a,b,c,d},SamplingPeriod->0.1]
```

[image]

```
processVariance=0.07;
measurementVariance=0.001;
processCovariance={{processVariance}};
measurementCovariance={{measurementVariance}};
kalmanEstimate=KalmanEstimator[{antenna,All,1},
    {processCovariance,measurementCovariance}]
```

[image]

The dimensions of the lower submatricies in `kalmanEstimate` have three rows.  In the next line  (`SystemsModelExtract`)  is used to ensure we only use the third row from the lower submatrices.  What are each of the rows in the lower submatrices (kalmanEstimate) above used for?

```
kalmanFilter=SystemsModelExtract[kalmanEstimate,All,{3}]
```

[image]